# Jest - How to ignore 'import' statements of files not available in current context

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm working with WordPress plugins, and I'm creating a plugin that is dependent on another plugin. Every plugin has it own Git repository.

When I do an import in my test like
`import pluginName from '../js/plugin_name.js'`
and that file contains another import of a file that does not exist in outside of Production I get an error `Cannot find module`

So my question is, how do I ignore that import statement?

I'm using `webpack` and `jsdom`

Answer (score 1):

If it is for the tests, you can try mocking the module with `jest.mock()` (https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules)

Something like:

```js
jest.mock('../js/plugin_name.js', () => {
  // implementation of what it should contain goes here
  // assuming that `pluginName` contains 2 methods:
  // .aMethod() and .anotherMethod(), it would be something like

  return {
    aMethod: jest.fn(), 
    anotherMethod: jest.fn(),
  }
})
```

If this import should happen only if running in production, you could set `NODE_ENV`, check it and do a dynamic import (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), like:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const pluginName = await import('../js/plugin_name.js');
}
```

Comment: It is not a 3rd party extension, just a file from another plugin I created inside WordPress. The file is only present when running in Dev. So it's complaining that the file is not there... eg the TEST imports a file. That file contains another import to a file that does not exist

Comment: @UnknownFrequency, added another possible solution in the answer: doing conditional imports.